# Upload to DocLib with jQuery (and REST) without HTML5

Tags: 2013, client-object-model, jquery, file-upload, rest

Uploading Documents to SP 2013 with jQuery and REST work just fine ([Properties when uploading Files using REST in SP 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/74969/properties-when-uploading-files-using-rest-in-sp-2013)) but these methods require a HTML5 compatible browser. The problem is now I also have to target older browsers.

I found a nice jQuery Plugin (https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) which looks very promising and should do the job. e.g. wrapping in an iframe for older browsers. So I configured it the same as previously but it does not work. I guess you have to provide `data` as a base64 encoded arraybuffer when using REST. Is there a way to upload a file (can also be witouth REST) to a DocLib, ideally with this plugin?

Configuration:

```
function initializeUploader() {
    // Init Uploader
    $('#fileInput').fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
        url: getRESTUrl(),

        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },

        add: function (e, data) {
            data.context = $('#SubmitButton').val('Start Upload')
                .click(function () {
                    //url = getRESTUrl();
                    data.context = $('<p/>').text('Uploading...').replaceAll($(this));
                    data.submit();
                });
        },

        done: function (e, data) {
            data.context.text("upload finished");
        },

        fail: function (e, data) {
            data.context.text("upload failed");
        }
    });

function getRESTUrl() {
    var serverurl = SPWeb.get_serverRelativeUrl() + "/Lists/TestDocLib";
    var targetRESTUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl +
                        "/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('" + serverurl + "')/Files" +
                        "/Add(url='testfile.png',overwrite=true)";
    return targetRESTUrl;
}
```

Errors I receive in the LOGS:

> SPRequest.PutFile: UserPrincipalName=[...], AppPrincipalName= ,bstrUrl=http://{myweb} ,bstrWebRelativeUrl=Lists/TestDocLib/testfile.png ,cbFile=38862 ,punkSPFileMgr= ,punkFFM= ,PutFileOpt=1 [...]
>
> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException:
> 0x80070003There is no
> file with URL 'http://{site}/Lists/TestDocLib/testfile.png' in this
> Web., StackTrace:

I don't know why SP (obivously) wants to retrieve the file. Previously I also had to specify the target filename and it just worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have built a jQuery library that includes a file upload widget.   I have tested it in SP 2007, 2010 and 2013 and its been working great.  See project site here: http://purtuga.github.io/SPWidgets/

The widget you want to look at is SPControlUpload.

The project has a quick SPA demo page that you can upload to a document library and quickly play with all widgets provided.

Comment: Thank you that looks very interesting. I will try it out on Monday. Until then... is there a way to specify the target filename?

Comment: No, you can't specify a target file.  But once uploaded you can use one of the API's to Change the file name.

Comment: Ok but this will leave me with the problem that, if I specify `overwrite=false`, the user will get a error message if the file already exists? With REST this was possible. This will only leave me with a temporary Doc Lib which performs checks and renames the file in an EventReceiver before copying it to the final Doc Lib I guess?

Comment: Correct.  Setting overwrite to false will give you an error if the file already exists. There are ways to copy a file from one document library to another.  I don't know about REST but WebServices has copy operations.

Answer (score 0):

Your server relative URL is wrong.  Libraries are not found at `<site url>/lists/<library>`, but rather `<site url>/<library>`.  So just remove `/lists` from your url, and it should work.

Comment: I don't know about SP Online but my lists are always under `/Lists/`. At least if they are deployed with Visual Studio. Also this was not the problem back then.