# Assign Meta-Data to Doc-Lib-Item with Rest in a ajax chain

Tags: document, file-upload, rest, ajax

i developed a custom Upload-Form to be able to upload a local file and pre-populate Metadata Fields at once. So the file will be uploaded to a document library and specific meta data fields will be set.

I followed as Rob described here:

[Properties when uploading Files using REST in SP 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/74969/properties-when-uploading-files-using-rest-in-sp-2013)

Uploading the Document works fine. Getting the Item Returns "200 OK" and I have checked the Response in Detail. Everything ok here. But the metadata is not updated, nor do I see an error message.

```
    var call = uploadDocument(buffer, fileName);
    call.done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        var call2 = getItem(data.d); // From here i can see that getItem and so data.d is fine!
        call2.done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            var item = data.d;
            var call3 = updateItemFields(item);
            call3.done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                var div = jQuery("#message");
                div.text("Item added");
            });
            call3.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                failHandler(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
            });
        });
    call2.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            failHandler(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
        });
    });
    call.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        failHandler(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
    });
```

Does anybody know how to identify what's missing here?

Answer (score 0):

After two nights of Research and Debugging, i can tell that the jQuery promises in Version 1.10.2 are not working properly.
At least i used `$.when(..).then(..).then(..).done(...)` with no luck in runtime but sometime in a debug-session it worked to the 2nd chain, never to the last.

You may find this interesting:
https://gist.github.com/domenic/3889970

I then decided to use code behind and that works like a charm with even less code.

Comment: Hi Ronny, it would be terrific if you could add the code you used :)

Comment: Hi Robert, for some reason I never got an notification about your question. Are you still interested in that Piece of Server Code?