# Adding a new item to a Document Library Using JSOM

Tags: document-library, updatelistitems, jsom

I need to add a new item in a document library using `JSOM`. The document library also possesses custom columns.

I am able to upload file but unable to get proper method to add the custom column values to the library using JSOM.

Following is the code that I have used for updating:

```
function receivedBinary() {
  clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
  parentList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("Lib_MasterDataDetails");
  fileCreateInfo = new SP.FileCreationInformation();
  fileCreateInfo.set_url(file.name);
  fileCreateInfo.set_overwrite(true);
  fileCreateInfo.set_content(new SP.Base64EncodedByteArray());
  var arr = convertDataURIToBinary(this.result);
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
      fileCreateInfo.get_content().append(arr[i]);
   }
  newFile = parentList.get_rootFolder().get_files().add(fileCreateInfo);
  clientContext.load(newFile);
  clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function (newFile) {
  var myListItem = newFile.get_listItemAllFields();
  myListItem.set_item("ClientLegalName", "NewValue");
  myListItem.update();
  clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function (sender, args) {
         console.log("Item updated");
     }, genericFailHandler);
  }, genericFailHandler);
}
```

Comment: can try this. Though it is not using JSOM. It is using jquery http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/75114/21421

Comment: @AtishDipongkor Thank you for comment but there they are using Rest API, but i want this to be done using JSOM

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to upload the file using the `SP.FileCreationInformation` object, you can write to the list item that corresponds to the file by calling `<file>.get_listItemAllFields()`

When you use `get_listItemAllFields()` you'll have a regular list item object that you can use `get_item()` and `set_item()` on.

Here is a complete example, you can paste the entire thing into your browser dev tools and run it, just sub the list name in `var oList` and the field name in `myListItem.set_item("Note", "NewValue")`

```
var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
var oList = oWebsite.get_lists().getByTitle("Documents");

var fileCreateInfo = new SP.FileCreationInformation();
fileCreateInfo.set_url("my new file.txt");
fileCreateInfo.set_content(new SP.Base64EncodedByteArray());
var fileContent = "The content of my new file";

for (var i = 0; i < fileContent.length; i++) {
    fileCreateInfo.get_content().append(fileContent.charCodeAt(i));
}

var newFile = oList.get_rootFolder().get_files().add(fileCreateInfo);
var myListItem = newFile.get_listItemAllFields();
myListItem.set_item("Note", "NewValue")

myListItem.update();
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function(sender, args) {
    // success on setting item values
    console.log("Item updated");
}, genericFailHandler);

function genericFailHandler(sender, args) { 
    console.log(args.get_message());
}
```

**Edit**: I've included a complete working snippet, substitute the string in `fileContent` for the actual contents of your file and you should be up and running; but this example will create a sample text file then modify one of its list item field values. You can also do this with a single call to `executeQueryAsync`, so I've updated my answer to show that too.

Comment: Hi John, Thanks for your reply,i have tried this already and it is not working in this way while we add an item to the document library. I can only be able to upload the file using SP.FileCreationInformation(), but cannot able to update the custom fields.

Comment: No Issues John, thanks for your feedback and Yes I am new to sharepoint. In my project I have a scenario where I am facing this issue. I tried various wys to add the custom fields but I cannot..:( Could you please help me on this?

Comment: Hi John, i tried like what u mentioned but it not updating, in listitem creation we use item.update(), in the same manner i used here once assigned the value with set_item(), but its showing item.update is not a function

Comment: Thank you so much I tried as you told,still not working, its throwing an exception,"newFile.get_listItemAllFields(); is not a function"...

Comment: @Sri updated to include an entire working example that you can paste into your browser tools

Comment: Now It is working fine. Ican able to upload the list items as well. Thank you so much. But still I am wonder,how it works? Because the code that I have mentioned above is working fine now with a slight modification, I just declared the file object(newFile) globally before, now I modified and declared in the method itself. How come it is working now? Did u get any idea?

Comment: It depends on many factors, variable scoping within Javascript can be very unclear sometimes. I added one more update to remove the second call to `executeQueryAsync` since after some testing I realize it's not actually needed

Answer (score 1):

What you want is not easy to explain and long.

I recommend you to use REST API instead JSOM. JSOM can upload file up to 1.5M according MSDN.

As I say the solution is long and if you want to, you can visit this post, is in Spanish and written by me just a few minutes ago as an answer to your problem.

The function is a little long

```
function GuardarArchivosAcciones(archivo) {
    var getFile = getFileBuffer(archivo);
    getFile.done(function(arrayBuffer) {
        var doUpload = uploadDocumentAcciones(arrayBuffer, archivo.name);
        doUpload.done(function(file, status, xhr) {
            var getItem = getListItemDocument(file.d.ListItemAllFields.__deferred.uri);
            getItem.done(function(listItem
            , status, xhr) {
                var doGetListItemEntityTypeFullName = getListItemEntityTypeFullNameAcciones();
                doGetListItemEntityTypeFullName.done(function(archivo, status, xhr) {
                    var itemMetadata = {
                            '__metadata': {
                                'type': archivo.d.ListItemEntityTypeFullName
                            },
                            'AccionId': (data)
                    };

                    jQuery.ajax({
                        url: listItem.d.__metadata.uri,
                        data: JSON.stringify(itemMetadata),
                        type: 'POST',
                        contentType: 'application/json;odata=verbose',
                        headers: {
                            'X-HTTP-Method': 'MERGE',
                            'X-RequestDigest': $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                            'Accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
                            'IF-MATCH': '*'
                        },
                        success: function(item) { 
                            Alert('Documento subido exitosamente');
                        },
                        error: function(err) {
                            Alert('Falló la subida de los archivos');
                        },
                        complete: function(item) { }
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
}
```

[Upload files REST](https://garabound.wordpress.com/2015/09/23/subiendo-archivos-con-metadata-con-full-rest-api/)

Answer (score -1):

Try this code.

```
byte[] content = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("file_content");

ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(new Uri("http://your_site/"));
List l = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Shared Documents");

File f = l.RootFolder.Files.Add(
       new FileCreationInformation() { Url = "File.aspx", Overwrite = true, Content = content }
   );

ListItem item = f.ListItemAllFields;
item["ContentType"] = "Basic Page";

ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: This is not JSOM. It is CSOM.