# renaming the upload file and save

Tags: sharepoint-online

[Properties when uploading Files using REST in SP 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/74969/properties-when-uploading-files-using-rest-in-sp-2013)

the above question solves to upload the file and fields and save it , is there any way that we can change the name of file and save it. Where should i add the code to rename the file to the above question.

Ex : i upload file as 1.doc but when saving it should be one.doc , is that possible,

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not just create an workflow to achieve your requirement?

Answer (score 1):

You can create workflow and use "Set Field in Current Item" action and choose "Start workflow automatically when an item is created":
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this very detailed [MSDN Documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/upload-a-file-by-using-the-rest-api-and-jquery) to upload/rename via REST in same and different domain.

> Article has the detailed step but skeleton would be like below.
>
> - Read file from client.
> - Upload file to SharePoint.
> - Get document from the uploaded source.
> - Rename and save it back.
>
> **Note:** You cannot rename file without uploading.

Comment: if you're going to quote content from a link, it needs to be the meat of the content, not a summary or glossary; that helps no one.